# Traveling via Turkey

Tags: layovers, tourist-visas, istanbul, malaysian-citizens

Do I need a transit visa at Istanbul Airport to enter Istanbul for city sightseeing? I am Malaysian citizen and I booked Turkish Airline flights to  Malaysia (from Nice to Kuala Lumpur) with a 10-hour layover at Istanbul Airport.

Comment: Be careful with the traffic though - 10 hours is a short duration in Istanbul

Answer (score 1):

No, you don't need a visa. Malaysian citizens are exempted from visa as stated by [Turkish MFA](http://www.mfa.gov.tr/visa-information-for-foreigners.en.mfa).

> Malaysia: Ordinary and official passport holders are exempted from
>   visa for their travels up to 90 days.